# What is spectrum permutation?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

This [paper](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/netmit/sFFT/soda_paper.pdf) refers to the concept of "spectrum perumutation" on page 4. I'm having a difficult time understanding what it means to permuate a signal. This is mainly due to the fact I don't understand the "invertible mod n" means.

What exactly happens to a signal when we permutate it? What does it look like in the time domain and what does it look like in the frequency domain?

Comment: You know what a *permutation* is, right? The exchange of indices in a sequence. That's exactly what they're doing here. Invertible in this context (only read the paragraph so far) means "the multiplication with $\sigma$ under mod $n$ is invertible, i.e. given the result of that multiplication and $\sigma$, you can caclulate the original value in all cases." Example: let's say we're  $x\in \mathbb Z \mod 13$, and you multiply by $\sigma = 7$, you get $x\sigma = 4 \mod 13$. You know that $x=8$! (because 7·8  = 56, and 56 mod 13 = 4, and it's only that easy because this is a prime field).

Comment: (and that works for any possible result $xz\in \mathbb Z\mod 13$, because $\sigma$ is coprime to 13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reminder what a *permutation* is: The exchange of indices in a sequence.

That's exactly what they're doing here.

Invertible in this context (only read the paragraph so far) means

"the multiplication with $\sigma$ under mod $n$ is invertible, i.e. given the result of that multiplication and $\sigma$, you can caclulate the original value in all cases."

Let's do an example:

let's say we're  $x\in \mathbb Z 
\setminus 13$, and you multiply by $\sigma = 7$, you get $x\sigma = 4 \mod 13$. You know that $x=8$, undisputably! (because 7·8  = 56, and 56 mod 13 = 4, and it's only that easy because this is a prime field).

That works for any possible result $xz\in \mathbb Z\setminus 13$, because $\sigma$ is coprime to 13; so, $\sigma$ is invertible for $(\cdot,\mathbb Z \setminus 13)$.

I picked that 13 because it's prime, and prime numbers are by definition coprime to any smaller integer.

Let's do an counter-example of that:

For FFTs, the length is usually not a prime number, but can be any natural integer. $n=2^m, m \in \mathbb N$ is a very common FFT length (because you can decompose it easily using simple butterflies); then, not every $n$ is invertible in the sense above: for example, if your multiplication $x\cdot4 = 0 \mod 32$, you can't say whether $x=0$, $x=8$ or $x=16$; it's not invertible.

Comment: I actually couldn't find a definition of permutation anywhere in this context - thank you. Regarding the permutation transformation here, Could you speak on the exact permutation transform they're proposed? They seem to be multiplying the input signal by sigma and offset it by tau. Is this correct?

Comment: no; they multiply the *indices* of the input values with $\sigma \mod n$: That's the permutation

Comment: Ahhh, that's what I meant to say. The indices being multiplied essentially result in the coefficients being moved to different bins. The offset being added results in a phase change of each coefficient.

Comment: exactly! and that, wonderfully, leads to a permuted spectrum.